# how to transfer data between servlet and jsp?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I would like to transfer data from servlet to jsp. 
When I transfer servlet to jsp using following code.

```
 RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("test2.jsp");
 rd.forward(request, response);
```

And then I would like to add request.setAttribute() method for jsp by using the following code.

```
 <%=request.getAttribute("str1") %>
```

So. My code is like that:
**In Servlet**

```
request.setAttribute("str1", "Test1");
request.setAttribute("str2", "Test2");
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("test2.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

**In JSP**

```
<body>
    <p>This is <%=request.getAttribute("str1") %>.</p>
    <p>This is <%=request.getAttribute("str2") %>.</p>
</body>
```

Error will occurs when dispatch to jsp.

```
SEVERE: Error loading WebappClassLoader
  delegate: false
  repositories:
    /WEB-INF/classes/
----------> Parent Classloader:
org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@18c56d
 test2.jsp
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test2.jsp
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1360)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1083)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:806)
    at org.apache.catalina.servlets.InvokerServlet.serveRequest(InvokerServlet.java:361)
    at org.apache.catalina.servlets.InvokerServlet.doPost(InvokerServlet.java:170)
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>  at org.apache.catalina.servlets.InvokerServlet.doPost(InvokerServlet.java:170)
> ```

That line of the stacktrace tells that you're either running a completely outdated version of Tomcat which has the old (and currently deprecated/removed) `InvokerServlet` by default turned on (Tomcat 4.x), or has a mediocre Tomcat version (5.x-6.x) which has it by default deprecated/disabled but is somehow manually been turned on (that person was apparently not aware about the [security holes](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Miscellaneous#Q3)). That servlet has been removed in Tomcat 7.x.

The invoker servlet is by default mapped on an URL pattern of `/servlet/*` and accepts only full qualified servlet classes in the URI path info like `/servlet/com.example.MyServlet`.

The exception message

> ```
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test2.jsp
> ```

is basically telling that it cannot find the "servlet" `test2.jsp` which you're trying to invoke by the URI `/servlet/test2.jsp`.

You're thus attempting to forward to a JSP from inside a servlet which is by itself called by that `InvokerServlet`. The `ServletRequest#getRequestDispatcher()` namely resolves the path **relative** to the current request URI (see also [its javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRequestDispatcher%28java.lang.String%29)).

So, to fix your particular problem, you need to specify an absolute path instead. Assuming that your JSP is placed in the root of the webcontent, just prefix with `/`. E.g.

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/test2.jsp");
```

That said, I really recommend to turn off that invoker servlet. It's completely outdated and full of vulrenability holes. I'd suggest to get yourself a nice [Tomcat 7](http://tomcat.apache.org) and throw away far that decade-old JSP/Servlet tutorial/book which you're currently reading. Take a peek in [our servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://www.coderanch.com/t/361886/Servlets/java/Error-loading-WebappClassLoader-Why

The exception being thrown is not around your code, there are some other issues in your setup, so I suggest fix them first. Have you installed tomcat properly and have set environment variables appropriately?